# AWS Amplify Costs

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am currently building a react based web application and creating the different CRUDS, apparently every time I create a new item or work in general with the CRUD the requests are increasing by the hundreds. I wonder why my free tier requests are almost finished, is this normal? Where could I see a log of what services are being used for such an increase.

[image]

Any information would be appreciated

Thank you